# Problema con linear-gradient en firefox

Tags: html, css, web

estoy empezando en CSS y tengo un problema con los gradientes, tengo lo siguiente:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSat - Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo empresa"/>
        </div>
        <div id="login-form">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/><br/><br />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/><br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
}

#container{
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top: 100px;
}
```

En Mozilla firefox, este gradiente no se muestra del todo bien:
[image: Imagen gradiente firefox]

Pero, sin embargo, tanto en Edge como en IE si se ve correctamente:
[image: Imagen gradiente edge]

Alguien sabe por que ocurre esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el gradiante se repite porque el body no ocupa el 100% de la altura de la ventana.

Podrias mover el background al `html` y agregar `background-attachment`:

```css
html {
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(97,57,1,1) 47%, rgba(255,158,0,1) 100%);

  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, problema solucionado.